# How should I remove noise in this image using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I'm trying to use `cv2.HoughLines` to identify the skew angle of the words in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K602F.jpg).
However, after edge detection, it [clearly has too much noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew8h3.jpg).

I've tried using `cv2.medianBlur` to remove the noise.
However, there is [even more noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0tqR.jpg).

This means that I'm unable to set the minimum line length threshold for hough transform.

What other functions should I be looking at?

Image:
[image]

After edge detection:
[image]

Edit: After Rotem's help, my code now identifies images with skew angles between 90 to -90 degrees including 90 but excluding -90.

```
import numpy as np
import imutils
import math
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread('omezole.jpg')

resized = imutils.resize(img, width=300)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th3 = cv2.threshold(gray, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
minLineLength = 50
maxLineGap = 3
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(th3, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=maxLineGap)
colLineCopy = cv2.cvtColor(th3,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

#Draw but remove all vertical lines, add corresponding angle to ls
ls = []
for line in lines:

    if line is None:
        angle = 0
    else:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0].tolist()
        print(line)
        #check for vertical lines since you can't find tan90
        if (x2-x1==0):
            ls.append(-90)
        else:
            ls.append((math.degrees(math.atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1)))))
            cv2.line(colLineCopy, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,250), 2)

#special case of strictly vertical words, if more than 0.2 of the lines are vertical assume, words are vertical
if ls.count(-90)>len(ls)//5:
    angle = 90
else:
    for angle in ls:
        if angle < -80:
            ls.remove(angle)
    angle = sum(ls)/len(ls)

rotated = imutils.rotate_bound(resized, -angle)
cv2.imshow("HoughLinesP", colLineCopy)
cv2.imshow("rotated", rotated)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(rotated, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshINV  = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

cv2.imshow("final", threshINV)
#Run OCR
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = r'--psm 11'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(threshINV, config = custom_config))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows

``
```

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post to include one. Showing your code will greatly simplify providing an answer. It is not "noise" that is your problem, you probably just need to find an appropriate threshold.

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36254219/alternative-to-opencv-fastnlmeansdenoising-for-real-time-application/36257443#36257443 Choose non-local means or for denoising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A useful way for removing the "noise", before using edge detection is applying a threshold that converts the image from Grayscale to binary image.

Finding the correct threshold (automatically) is not always an easy task.
I manually set the threshold value to 50.

Solution using `HoughLinesP` code sample:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read input image
img = cv2.imread('omezole.jpg')

# Convert from RGB to Grayscale.
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply threshold - all values below 50 goes to 0, and values above 50 goes to 1.
ret, thresh_gray = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


# https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html
edges = cv2.Canny(thresh_gray, 50, 150, apertureSize = 3)


minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 5
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=100, minLineLength=minLineLength, maxLineGap=maxLineGap)

# Draw lines
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0].tolist()
    cv2.line(img, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,255,0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('houghlines.png',img)
```

Result:

[image]

---

The `HoughLines` solution is not so robust.
I suggest another solution using `findContours`:

```
img = cv2.imread('omezole.jpg')

# Inverse polarity:
thresh_gray = 255 - thresh_gray;

# Use "open" morphological operation to remove some rough edges
thresh_gray = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh_gray, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((5, 5)))


# Find contours over thresh_gray
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

# Iterate contours
for c in cnts:
    # Only if contour area is large enough:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 2000:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        # convert all coordinates floating point values to int
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)
        angle = rect[2]
        print('angle = ' + str(angle))

cv2.imwrite('findcontours.png', img)

# Show result (for testing).
cv2.imshow('thresh_gray', thresh_gray)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:
[image]

```
angle = -21.801406860351562
angle = -21.44773292541504
angle = -21.370620727539062
angle = -21.801406860351562
angle = -22.520565032958984
angle = -22.56700897216797
angle = -23.198591232299805
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help, adjusting the threshold helped. If I understand correctly, the second method you suggested makes use of the boxes in the image, however, since I will run this code on other images without boxes, it may not work.